# Fomantic UI - TypeError: $(...).toast is not a function

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, fomantic-ui

I am using Meteor with React and Semantic-ui-react. I needed a toast function so I wanted to change to Fomantic UI. Everything related is loaded by NPM.

I removed semantic-ui-css and added fomantic-ui-css.

I removed the
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" />` from the head.

I changed all `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';` to `import 'fomantic-ui-css/semantic.css';`

When I try to execute a

```js
$('body')
  .toast({
    title: 'LOOK',
    message: 'See, how long i will last',
    showProgress: 'bottom'
  })
;
```

I get `TypeError: $(...).toast is not a function`

I can't find anything on it over various searches through SO and repository issues.

Thanks for any help you can give!!
Phil

Comment: From what I see you just imported css. Does the formantic package also deliver any js code? I assume there needs to be some js code loaded from the module in order to make the toast method available.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Was missing the minifier package: standard-minifier-css@1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to import the `semantic.js` file, which will add the functionality to your jquery instances:

```js
import 'fomantic-ui-css/semantic.js'
import 'fomantic-ui-css/semantic.css'
```

However, there is no need to import the `.min.*` minified files, because Meteor will use a js and css minifier when you build your app for production / deployment later.